# SVG Selenium click do not work

Tags: selenium, svg, click, action, crossfilter

I want to simulate a simple mouse click and drag within an svg element.
I managed to get the coordinates of my starting and ending point, both absolute (window coordinates) and relative to the encapsulating svg element.
Here is the code I am using to simulate the mouse:

```java
    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    builder.moveToElement(area, xStart, yStart);
    builder.clickAndHold();
    builder.moveToElement(area, xStop, yStop);
    builder.release();

    Action setFilter = builder.build();
    setFilter.perform();
```

Where area is a WebElement representing my svg and the coordinates are relative to that element. Note that:

```java
    area.getLocation(); // returns null
```

This made me wonder whether the webdriver is able to find that element at all. So I tried with absolute coordinates:

```java
    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    builder.moveByOffset(chart.getLocation().x + xStart, chart.getLocation().y + yStart);
    builder.clickAndHold();
    builder.moveByOffset(xStop - xStart, yStop - yStart);
    builder.release();

    Action setFilter = builder.build();
    setFilter.perform();
```

where chart is the div surrounding the svg element (note that the offset between the div position and the svg position is only 10 pixels and is not significant). That didn't work either and I also tried by relative position to the div but still no luck.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is it possible to use 'getLocation()' on the element containing the SVG instead?

Comment: Hi @Nashibukasan yes it is possible. I used getLocation on the containing div to get the (approximative) coordinates of the svg element. The svg and its descendant nodes will return null though.

Comment: Is it possible to use the approximate values returned to mathematically find the coordinates of your other elements? As to what the actual problem is, I am not sure sorry, but would be interested to see the outcome.

Comment: In this particular case I used the translate value of the svg sub element to calculate the offset. That value is visible in the dom tree and looks like this:   `<g transform="translate(10,10)"> ... </g>`

but it can also be accessed programmatically in javascript using `svgElement.getCTM()` or `svgElement.getScreenCTM()` . Note that these methods are defined in some of its subclasses but not in SVGElements itself.

Comment: I find that while my <svg> WebElement seems to present the right coordinates, dragging and dropping (even improvised versions) don't seem to work.  Not sure what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a hack for it to work but it requires the webpage to be opened on the foreground. If you're doing anything else at the same time it may break the test and I cannot say if it would work if ran remotely.

Here's what it looks like:

```java
  Robot robert = new Robot();
  robert.mouseMove(xStart, yStart);
  // full click once to get focus on the window
  robert.mousePress(MouseEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
  robert.mouseRelease(MouseEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
  // then set the filter
  robert.mousePress(MouseEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
  robert.mouseMove(xStop, yStop);
  robert.mouseRelease(MouseEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
```